# Problemas con <h:inputFile /> al capturar su nombre

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

cuando ingreso un archivo a través de un inputFile para ser capturado con file.getName() me trae por defecto un nombre que se asocia al id del inputFile, pero no me toma el nombre que trae el archivo al momento de cargarlo. como puedo cambiar esto para que tome el nombre de origen del archivo.

con este codigo capturo el archivo en la vista

```
<div class="col-lg-7"> 
    <h:inputFile id="file3" value="#{updateController.file}"  styleClass="btn btn-xs"/>
</div>
```

y aqui capturo la informacion para convertirlo en byteArray

```
public void upload() throws IOException{
    LOGGER.info("ingresando al metodo cargar archivo");
    try {
        if(file!=null) {
        attachmentValidator = 2;
        atacheByte = new byte[(int)file.getSize()];
        InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
        in.read(atacheByte);
        atachemeType = file.getContentType();
        nameAttachmanet = file.getName();
        LOGGER.info("Nombre del archivo: "+file.getName());

        }
        else
        {
            attachmentValidator = 1;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.info("error" + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

cuando imprimo el nombre que viene del archivo me trae formUpload:file3, ya que toma el id del h:form y del h:inputFile como nombre del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar el nombre del archivo que se esta subiendo, solo se debe usar el 
    'file.getSubmittedFileName()', en este caso quedaria :

```
public void upload() throws IOException{
    LOGGER.info("ingresando al metodo cargar archivo");     
    try {
        if(file!=null) {
        attachmentValidator = 2;
        atacheByte = new byte[(int)file.getSize()];
        InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
        in.read(atacheByte);
        atachemeType = file.getContentType();
        nameAttachmanet = file.getSubmittedFileName();//captura el nombre del archivo especificado por el cliente
        LOGGER.info("Nombre del archivo: "+file.getName());

        }
        else
        {
            attachmentValidator = 1;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.info("error" + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```